# Commutators of covariant derivative and Yang-Mills Field Strength in curved spacetime

Tags: gauge-theory, commutator, yang-mills, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I am stuck with YM Field Strength and commutator. For example, in flat spacetime we have the commutator
$$F_{\mu \nu}=[\partial_{\mu}+A_{\mu},\partial_{\nu}+A_{\nu}] .$$ But what is the thing in curved spacetime? I mean, with Riemann connection $\Gamma$, do we have
$$F_{\mu \nu}=[\partial_{\mu}+\Gamma_{\mu}+A_{\mu},\partial_{\nu}+\Gamma_{\nu}+A_{\nu}]?$$

How to compute such commutator?

Comment: How did you compute the first commutator? You expand it out, right? You do the same thing with the second commutator.